# ¿Cómo asignar una expresión y llamarla en los snippets para VSC

Tags: json, visual-studio, vscode, snippets

Estoy creando mis propios snippets para java en Visual Studio Code y quiero saber si se podría asignar una expresión a una variable y poder utilizarlo para acortar el body de los snippets.

En un ejemplo, lo que querría hacer es lo siguiente:

```
    "type": "${1|String,int,float,boolean|}"
    "for loop": {
        "prefix": "for",
        "body": [
            "for (type ${2: i} = $3; $4<=$5; $6) {", // Cambiar type a su valor
            "\t$7",
            "};"
        ]
    },
```